# Pagination of "Critique of pure reason"?

Tags: kant

I see that fragments from Kant's  "Critique of pure reason" are usually referenced according to the pagination of the first or second edition (Axxx or Bxxx respectively). And my translation does not have that information. Are you aware of some pagination table that allows to locale (albeit approximately) chapters/sections titles from the pages numbers?

Answer (score 4):

As you know, the Critique was published in two editions (A and B respectively); the numbers refer to the line number in each of the books. Unless you are reading an *original* copy of the second edition, virtually all translations should provide the Table of Contents (the table having been included by Kant himself in the first edition). The table in my Guyer/Wood translation does not provide Chapter/Section titles to line number pagination ("Axx or Bxx"), but uses the pages of the translation book itself, which takes you directly to the line number pagination you need.

I don't know of any direct **Chapter/section titles to line number pagination**, but it wouldn't be that hard to figure out if you have a table of contents.